# How to power on EC2 instance 3rd week of month and power off at other times?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use a lambda function with cloudwatch event to power on/off an instance for 1 week a month.

I realised cron can't do week of month, so I started looking at using the lambda script to detect the week and turn on/off depending on that.

Couldn't get any of the python week of month code I came across to work.

So I figured try 3rd monday and 3rd sunday for two different functions to power on and off respectively.

Realised the error of my ways, as if the month started on a tues-sunday, the power off condition would occur before the power on condition.

So I figured I'd open the question up to others, any strategies to execute this?  I've seen AWS scheduler, but I wanted to get more experience with lambda and cloudwatch, so I'm trying to do this myself.

Comment: Why python code? You haven't show any.

Comment: Run the Lambda once a day at the time you'd normally want to start the EC2.  Have the code determine if it's the correct week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be:

- Configure CloudWatch Events to trigger an AWS Lambda function once per day
- The Lambda function should:
- Check whether it is at the start of the 3rd week, if so then Start the instance
- Check whether it is at the start of the 4th week, if so then Stop the instance

This logic will take less than 1 second to execute, so don't think of it as wasteful to have it running every single day. Also, you will have complete control over the definition of "3rd week of the month".